# Cannot require certain version of a non-module Go package

Tags: go, go-modules, moby

I want to require a certain version of a Go package that has not yet been converting to using modules, I want to require this in my `go.mod` file.  Specifically, the package is "github.com/docker/docker/pkg/system@v19.03.13"

When I run the following command, I get the following output:

```
$ go get -v github.com/docker/docker/pkg/system@v19.03.13
go: found github.com/docker/docker/pkg/system in github.com/docker/docker v17.12.0-ce-rc1.0.20200916142827-bd33bbf0497b+incompatible
```

As you can see, the version `v17.12.0-ce` is downloaded, not `v19.03.13`.  I did also notice the "+incompatible" suffix, but I am not sure that has anything to do with the issue.  According to the [docs](https://golang.org/ref/mod#incompatible-versions)

> the go command adds an +incompatible suffix to versions with major version 2 or higher without a go.mod file. +incompatible indicates that a version is part of the same module as versions with lower major version numbers; consequently, the go command may automatically upgrade to higher +incompatible versions even though it may break the build.

so I understand that this package does not have a `go.mod` file, however the downloaded version (17.x) is greater than 2, so I don't think `+incompatible` is the issue.

my question is: When I specify version `v19.03.13`, why does Go install `v17.12.0-ce`?

[This](https://github.com/moby/moby/tree/v19.03.13) is the version I want to use

[This](https://github.com/moby/moby/tree/v17.12.0-ce) is the one that is downloaded

Comment: The version doesn't matter, since it's not a module and is generating a synthetic version based on the best guess of the parent tree. Look at the commit id, and you'll see you're also getting the latest commit from `v19.03.13`

Comment: hey @JimB , good eye, do you want to add this as an answer and I can mark it correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version listed in the `go.mod` [pseudo-version](https://golang.org/ref/mod#glos-pseudo-version) does not matter for repositories that are not go modules. The version `v19.03.13` is not a syntactically valid semantic version, so the go tool will walk up commit tree to find one, and the first valid semver it encounters happens to be `v17.12.0` (which is not intended to be a semantic version, but it is at least valid). The fact that the leading version isn't what is expected in the pseudo-version isn't a problem as long as go itself can reproduce and parse the result.

If you look at the trailing commit hash, you have `bd33bbf0497b`, which is the correct commit id for the `v19.03.13` tag.

Comment: `v19.03.13` is not used as the pseudo-version base because it is not syntactically valid as a [semantic version](https://semver.org/).

Comment: Unfortunately, `v17.12.0-ce-rc1` is syntactically valid as both a semantic version and a [calendar version](https://calver.org/). In the Docker repo it is intended as the latter, but the `go` command interprets it as the former.